# Tax return accepted, amended return rejected

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income-tax-refund, amended-tax-return

My original tax return was efiled and accepted by both US and state. I originally forgot to include daycare expenses for my daughter which would have provided an additional several hundred dollars to my return. I amended my return, but it was rejected because I forgot to include my 1098-T to back up my college expenses. I've found that I don't have receipts to corroborate my expenditures on books, so my amended return would provide < $100. Since I initiated an amended tax return, am I obligated to continue, or will the IRS make me file the amended return or try to audit me? At this point it's not worth my time.

Comment: If the amended return was rejected, it is as though it was never submitted. If the IRS sent a letter saying that you need to submit Documents A, B and C in order for the IRS to accept the submitted amended return, then either you have to submit the required documents or tell the IRS that you cannot, in which case there will be an IRS-issued correction saying "We have denied the following claims; according to our computations, your tax is $X." together with instructions on what to do if you disagree.

Comment: @DilipSarwate You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: They sent the entire return back to me with a cover letter saying: 1) I forgot to sign the return ^_^   and 2) They needed the 1098-T. It sounds like this falls into the latter category you discuss. How would I go about telling the IRS I can't produce the documents they require? Would this cause them to modify my return to not include any of my tuition expenses? It sounds like I would be better off if I continue to file the amended return.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer to question as amended by OP's comment.

Since you did not sign the amended return paperwork, there 
is *no* amended return that has been submitted to the IRS 
(even if IRS kept a copy of the submitted paperwork in its 
files).

At this point, you have several options.

- You can just forget the whole thing.  Your accepted return is
  your tax return for 2011.  But see below for what acceptance means.
- You can submit a properly signed amended return together
  with the 1098-T.  If there are other changes
  in your amended return, the IRS will typically accept the
  ones that are properly validated and reject the rest.  In this
  case, you will get a letter telling you what changes the IRS has 
  made to your submitted (amended) return, and what to do
  if you disagree with the changes.  If additional tax, interest,
  or penalties are due, the IRS will tell you to how to pay the
  amount due.
- Note that in the normal scheme of things, once a tax return
  (whether original or amended) showing a refund is due
  is keyed into the IRS computers, you might get the refund within
  a few weeks of submission if no *arithmetic errors* are found in 
  the numbers you submitted.  The IRS will take a closer look at your
  return somewhat later, and the letter
  saying that upon closer examination, some changes have been
  made to your return, might come much later.  When a
  tax return is *accepted,* it merely means 
  that the return has been found to have no
  obvious numerical errors.  The IRS has three years
  from the due date of the original return (including extensions
  of time to file, if requested) to examine the return
  in detail.  If the return is amended, a new three-year
  clock starts from the date of filing the amended return.

As a final comment, if you amend your Federal return,
you might need to amend your State income tax return also,
so don't forget that part.  If you submitted your
amended return to the State when you sent in your
unsigned Federal amended return, and the State amended return
has been accepted already, then if you
now decide to *not* amend your Federal return after all,
you will need to file yet another amended State return 
saying put everything back the way it was.

Comment: +1 important point about the state return being tied to the federal...